# RecognizerIntent change default language

Tags: java, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i start the RecognizerIntent with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,"us-US");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH_GUEST);
```

but my phone is configurated in italian and when i speech for example "Wait a minute" it return me "uait a minut"(the italian pronunciation).
Why? 
Best Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
String language =  "us-US";
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,language);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language); 
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH_GUEST);
```

Comment: As of Android Oreo, this is the Intent parameter that you really need to change: intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);  ...The rest are overkill, but anyways, you solved your problem!